# Pointers not giving expected result

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner. I was working around with pointer when I found something strange:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int* fun(int*);

int main()
{
    int i=4,*j;
    j=fun(&i);
    printf("%d ",*j);//gives correct answer -> how??
    printf("%d",*j);//gives incorrect answer
}

int* fun(int *i)
{
    int k;
    k=*i;
    return (&k);
}
```

In `main(), I am using`printf("%d ",*j);` 2 times. First one is giving me right answer, but second one is not. Why?

but this is working fine-
    ‎#include
    int *func();

```
int main()
{
int *p;
p=func();
printf("%u", p);
printf("\n%d", *p);
printf("\n%d", *p);
printf("\n%d", *p);
printf("\n%d", *p);

}

int* func()
{
int i=10;
printf("%u", &i);
printf("\n%d", i);
return (&i);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 8):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by returning a pointer to a local variable. After the function `fun` returns, the space occupied by the local variable `k` is not valid anymore. Actually the space on the stack previously used by `fun` is probably overwritten by the first call to `printf`.

Comment: I have added a new code which is working fine. In this I have defined variable as local in func again, but have assigned it a value there only.

Comment: @bhavneet If it works, it's because you are lucky, not because it really works. It's still undefined behavior to return addresses to local variables.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the address of a variable that's local to `fun`; once `fun` exits, that variable no longer exists, and the pointer is no longer valid.  Strictly speaking, the behavior is undefined.

What's most likely happening is that the memory location that `k` used to occupy gets overwritten after the first call to `printf`.

Comment: I have added a new code which is working fine. In this I have defined variable as local in func again, but have assigned it a value there only.

Comment: It *appears* to be working fine; that's one of the possible outcomes of invoking undefined behavior.  Once `func` exits, `i` no longer exists, and that memory location will eventually be overwritten by something else.  What you are doing is a coding error, period.